# overrode table-bordered boostrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I use this library :
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#welcome.html

When the table is created a table it includes the table-bordered
But when I try to override the css for table-bordered it not work

thank you.

example

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="selected" data-sort-order="asc" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-buttons-class="primary" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-id-field="selected" data-select-item-name="selected" class="table table-md table-hover table-striped table-bordered" data-mobile-responsive="true" data-check-on-init="true">

    <thead class="dataTableHeadingRow"><tr><th class="bs-checkbox " style="width: 36px; " data-field="0"><div class="th-inner "><label><input name="btSelectAll" type="checkbox"><span></span></label></div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th class="text-md-center" style="" data-field="selected"><div class="th-inner sortable both asc">id</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style="" data-field="2"><div class="th-inner "></div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th style="" data-field="3"><div class="th-inner "></div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th class="text-md-center" style="" data-field="products"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Produits</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th class="text-md-center" style="" data-field="status"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Statut</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th>
</thead>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly are you trying to acoumplish? If you don't want borders for the grid, just use the `table-borderless` class on the `<table>` element.
[as the docs says here](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because other elements of the table also get styled by it. If you are generating the table with js, then you could specify the `table-borderless` class, like

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  classes: 'table table-borderless table-hover'
  columns: [{
  ...
  }]
});
```

If you're generating with html, then use the `data-classes` attribute.

Otherwise, you would have to individually remove the borders from each element, something like this I suppose

```
.table-bordered, .table-bordered th, .table-bordered tr, .table-bordered td{
    border: 0;
}
```